# object sometimes through the plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning to use Unity and I have a problem with a little game we've seen in a course. Is the maze game and the ball where you must move the maze to bring the ball to the goal. The problem is that the ball , sometimes , through the plane of the maze and falls into the void.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class controllaberinto : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public enum TGameState
    {
        PLAYING=0,
        END_GAME
    }
    public float RotationalSpeed;
    public GameObject Ball;
    Vector3 StartPosition;
    public TGameState GameState;

    void Start () 
    {
        StartPosition = Ball.transform.position;    
    }   
    void Update () 
    {
        switch (GameState) 
        {
        case TGameState.PLAYING:
            UpdatePlayingGameState();
            break;
        }   
    }
    void UpdatePlayingGameState()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
           transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, RotationalSpeed*Time.deltaTime));
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
           transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0.0f, 0.0f, -RotationalSpeed*Time.deltaTime));
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
           transform.Rotate(new Vector3(RotationalSpeed*Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
           transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-RotationalSpeed*Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f));

    }
}
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.*

Comment: How is this related to c#? do you create the collisions in code? if this is solely about the gameengine without any problem regarding code you should post this in the official Unity community.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first Question here and I forgot to show the code. I don't know if it's a coding error or game engine. Thank you very much for the answers

Comment: Just for the record, it's a lot more helpful if you copy/paste the code and put it in a code block (just indent it), that way people can copy/paste, test, edit, etc... As to your problem, are you implementing collision detection yourself or are you using unity's physics engine? Have you applied to appropriate colliders to all objects? Also, the [GameDev SE Site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) is a more appropriate fit for this question as it relates to the Unity engine more than C#. You're more likely to find an answer there

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes in writing the question. I have reviewed the colliders and seems fine. The ball falls just sometimes, not always. Especially in a corner as the plane maze rotates with much inclination.

Comment: No worries, it's an uncommon site format if you're not familiar with Stack Exchange. If you've found a solution that you think will help others, please post it as an answer, then (when possible) accept it. This will let others know this question no longer needs an answer. On the other hand, if this question was in error, please delete it. Thanks very much and see you around.

Comment: Oh and for the record, I think the trick is to not move/rotate the ball directly, but rather to add force to the collider. See this tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/addforce

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that all walls have collider attached and it's not misplaced.

Second, does it happen when ball is moving really fast? If it is, that's common Unity problem where fixed physics timestamp is just too high. You can try decreasing this number or applying this script to ball: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DontGoThroughThings

Comment: Hi Rafal, thank you very much for answering. I checked the colliders and it seems that all is well.

It does not happen only when the speed is high because sometimes the ball crosses the plane just to start the game when the ball is stopped

Answer (score 0):

This problem is often caused by moving/rotating physics objects directly. When you rotate, the collider vertices move, it's inevitable that at some point you'll rotate the closest vertex through the plane.

Instead, you should apply forces to the object. It will give a more realistic movement. There's a [tutorial on adding](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/physics/addforce) forces that should get you started.

Comment: The code that I have written in the Question is the labyrinth, the ball does not have any code. The ball moves by gravity according to where the labyrinth is rotated. I think you mean, no? I'll watch the tutorial anyway, thank you very much, Basic.

Comment: Not a problem. I assumed the labyrinth was static and ball propelled along. That said, the same applies in reverse in both scenarios... Moving the labyrinth by rotating/transforming directly could cause it to move into the ball.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was not a matter of code, but in the components of the Unity.

Ball had his Rigidbody but forgot to put the labyrinth. Remember to add the Component rigidbody for 2 elements, and that the labyrinth does not affect the physic and falling into the void , do not select the "gravity" tab and select the  " is kinetic " tab, and will not affect gravity, but collisions will.